# FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.ftech, PID: 26369

Tags: kotlin

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ftech, PID: 26369
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08010e (com.example.ftech:id/itfr) for fragment Home{cc04782} (be693790-3532-4162-b9d6-7fe2e9dfa170 id=0x7f08010e)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:513)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:940)

package com.example.ftech.ftechafb

```
`    import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView

import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.ftech.ftechafb.Adapter.MyAdapter
import com.example.ftech.R
import com.example.ftech.ftechafb.Models.ItemViewModel


// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

private lateinit var viewModel : ItemViewModel
private lateinit var userRecyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var adapter: MyAdapter

class Home : Fragment() {

    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        return view
    }

    companion object {

        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            Home().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        userRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        userRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        userRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        adapter = MyAdapter()
        userRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ItemViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.allItems.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { itemList ->
            adapter.updateUserList(itemList)
        })



        val searchView = view.findViewById<SearchView>(R.id.searchView)
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                // Perform search when user submits the query
                query?.let {
                    adapter.filterItems(it)
                }
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                // Perform search as the user types
                newText?.let {
                    adapter.filterItems(it)
                }
                return true
            }
        })


    }


}`
```

i need to help mee to edit this code because i can not know what is the problem

Comment: Well you have no view for the home fragment in location.. look at the first part of your error. So you have something conflicting with the home fragment.. if you are not using parameters delete them.. that's what I do. However, the issue is there is no view referenced...No view found for id 0x7f08010e (com.example.ftech:id/itfr) for fragment Home{cc04782} (be693790-3532-4162-b9d6-7fe2e9dfa170 id=0x7f08010e)

Comment: but i did not have any conflict and the itfr id is on activity main not in fragment home

Comment: Read the error... It says there is no view referenced for the fragment home... What do you have in main activity